# JavaScript intercept access to array-like class

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a class that provides access to an array, along with some other methods. I would like to use an array of indices to intercept the access to the underlying array (& the array's length) but leave all of the other methods/properties unchanged. What's the best way to do this?

```
class ArrayLike {
  constructor(private array: number[]) {}

  n() {
    return this.array.length;
  }

  valueAt(index: number) {
    return this.array[index];
  }

  values() {
    const result = [] as number[];
    const n = this.n()
    for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) result.push(this.valueAt(i));
    return result;
  }

  otherMethod() {
    return "foo"
  }
}

// Could also be a method on ArrayLike
function proxyfy(arrayLike: ArrayLike, indices: number[]) {
  ...
}

const arrlike = new ArrayLike([3, 2, 1])
const arrlikeProxy = proxyfy(arrlike, [0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2])

arrlike.n() // 6
arrlike.values() // [3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1]
arrlike.otherMethod() // "foo"
```

Comment: `proxyfy` already has the solution in its name: use a `Proxy`!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand this correctly, but FWIW here's a proxy that intercepts numeric indexes:

```js
const makeProxy = (target, indexes) => new Proxy(target, {
    indexes,

    get(target, prop, receiver) {
        if (prop === 'length')
            return indexes.length
        if (typeof prop == 'string' && !isNaN(Number(prop)))
            return target[indexes[prop]]
        return target[prop]
    },
});

//

let a = ['A', 'B', 'C']
let myProxy = makeProxy(a, [0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 1])


console.log(...myProxy.values())
```